# Install Ubuntu 10.04 on ICH6R RAID 1

Tags: 10.04, installation, raid

I have a machine running Win7 in RAID 1 Mirror Array. I want to install Ubuntu 10.04 along Win on this machine.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Will Ubuntu recognize this automatically? Is there some commands to run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have learned:

ICH6R is considered a FakeRaid in the Linux/Ubuntu World.

There is this very complete guide to installing Ubuntu on a FakeRaid and also why it is considered a FakeRaid
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Here is quoted the relevant part for Ubuntu 10.04:

> ### Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) and 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)
>
> The installer will recognize the dmraid devices and allow you to use them normally. Their names will be /dev/mapper/something instead of /dev/sdX. You need to install grub to the dmraid device instead of /dev/sda. In 10.04 the final stage of the installation you check the advanced button and can select where to install grub to. In 10.10, you choose the destination from the drop down list on the manual partitioning screen.